# Is there a way to retrieve individual information from scanner input?

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to java programming and I'm suppose to read data from a separate text file in java and calculate the age of a person however I'm having trouble trying to get the calculation of the age right

Data in the text file:

First Name

Last Name

DOB (E.g. 15 Jan 1988)

Current Year (E.g. 2020)

Below is the code I'm using the read the data from the text file as well as the code I used to calculate the age however when I try to print the DOB it reads correctly but when I try to calculate it doesn't seem to do it correctly

```
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        int day = input.nextInt();
        Month month = Month.valueOf (input.next ()); //from an enum
        int year = input.nextInt();
        int currentYear = input.nextInt();

        hr.setFirstName (firstName);
        hr.setLastName (lastName);
        d.setDate (day, month, year);
        hr.setCurrentYear (currentYear);

    //the method to calculate age from another class
    public int getAge ()
    {
        Date d = new Date ();
        int age = currentYear - d.getYear();
        return age;
    }

   //code to print out the date of birth
   System.out.printf("Date of birth: %d %s %d \n", d.getDay(), d.getMonth(), d.getYear());
```

Comment: Why are you making a new Date object inside your function? You already did d.setDate in your variable list, so why not keep using the same variable?

Comment: What restrictions, if any, do you have on your assignment?

Comment: What problem do you have exactly? Do you get an error, or an unexpected result? Please provide more details.

Comment: You read the birth year from the file into `year`, yes?   And the current year into `currentYear`, yes?  You have what you need to compute the age ru]ight there, so why all the mucking about with `new Date()` and such?  Doesn't `int age = currentYear - year;` make more sense?

Comment: @JakeTheSnake as the getYear function is in another class hence to access it I figured that i had to include in a Date object however I tried removing it as well and did not get the desired outcome

Comment: @tobias_k The problems that I face is that when I try to print out the getAge () I get 2020 instead of 32

Comment: Then it might help to show the code that actually calls `getAge()` and prints the result.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I've tried doing `int age = currentYear - year;` and received an error however as the year is supposed to be stored into another hence I would have to access the year from that seperate class as well

Comment: @tobias_k the code I use to call getAge() is `System.out.println("Your age: " + hr.getAge() + " years old ");`

Comment: If you do `d = new Date()` that will be the current date, so `currentYear - d.getYear()` would print 0 or even a negative number. But if your actual output is `2020`, then there must be more problems in the code you do not show.

Comment: I have a setDOB as well as a getDOB method in the class as well however i'm unsure of how I should implement it into the code. I'm thinking along the lines of assigning a variable DOB to scan the DOB portion in the text file then to break it up and store it into separate variables however I'm unsure of how I am suppose to make that work

Comment: OK, so the _actual_ problem you're having is that you're reading the data from the text file in one class and trying to do something with i]that data in another class, but you don't know how to get the information from the one class to the other.  Does that sound more or less right?

Comment: @KevinAnderson the main problem that I have is actually trying to read and set the date of birth correctly to display it as I have a getDOB() and setDOB() functions that are not being used 

to read the first name and last name from the text file I used
String firstName = input.nextLine();
String lastName = input.nextLine();
however the part i'm unsure of is how I should read the date of birth correctly